# Слово "пожалуйста" всегда обособляется?

Tags: пунктуация, междометие, частицы

В каких случаях слово "пожалуйста" не выделяется запятой?

Как, например, объяснить знаки здесь:

> *Явился, здравствуйте пожалуйста, на нашу голову! Насорил? Здрасьте
>   пожалуйста! А кто убирать будет*?

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_547

Comment: Слово "пожалуйста" может выделяться или не выделяться запятыми. Если Вам сложно разобраться с этой темой по справочнику, то задайте предложение с этим словом.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не всегда.
Участник *@Степан Попов* дал вам хорошую ссылку, да и вы в вопросе **дословно** приводите словарную статью. Мне к этому добавить нечего — только подтверждающие примеры.
Вот что есть у М. А. Булгакова (надеюсь, что всеми любимого).

1. *Мне оставалось только выпучить глаза, что я и сделал, а Бомбардов продолжал:

   — На автора. В самом деле — группа старейшин рассуждала так: мы ищем, жаждем ролей, мы, основоположники, рады были бы показать все наше мастерство в современной пьесе и... [здравствуйте пожалуйста](http://rulibrary.ru/bulgacov/zapiski_pokojnika__teatralnyj_roman/63)! Приходит серый костюм и приносит пьесу...*
2. Ульяна (в передней). *Есть кто-нибудь? Ивана Васильевича не видели?* (Стучит в дверь Тимофеева, потом входит.) *[Здрасте пожалуйста](http://rulibrary.ru/bulgacov/ivan_vasilevich/12)! Его весь дом ищет, водопроводчики приходили, ушли... жена, как проклятая, в магазине за селёдками…*

[Здрасьте пожалуйста / здравствуйте пожалуйста](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/248/%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5) — междометие.
Выделяется знаками препинания или оформляется как отдельное предложение, при этом между словами ***здрасьте (здравствуйте)*** и **пожалуйста** знак препинания не ставится.